# How to prevent Proc report from printing a blank page when a variable flows over to the next page due to having too much text in it?

Tags: sas

---

I am using the below proc report code to produce a listing and the variable "m" has some records with very long text in it. Therefore, it sometimes flows over to the next page. When this happens, proc report generates a blank page before printing this variable on the next page. How can I prevent printing of this blank page in my final report? I am producing this report in the listing format. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
proc printto file="&outputpathname." new;
run;

ods escapechar='^';

%macro lafootnote(num,string);

footnote&num &string "%sysfunc(repeat(%str( ),250)))";

%mend;

%let undl=%sysfunc(repeat(_, 165));

options ps=58 ls=165 nodate center nonumber spool ;
    title1 "title1";
    title2 j=center "title2";
    title3 j=center "title3";

%lafootnote(1, "Program: &loc/&pgmname     Draft      
    %sysfunc(date(), yymmdd10.) %sysfunc(time(), tod5.)"   "         page#  ");

proc report data=&datain. nowd missing headskip headline split='@' formchar(2)='_';
  column ("&undl" a b c d e f g h i j k l n m);
  define a /order order=internal noprint;
  define b /order order=internal noprint;
  define c /order order=internal noprint;
  define d /order flow left width=7  'd';
  define e /display flow left width=12 'e';
  define f /display flow left width=10 'f';
  define g /display flow left width=13 'g';
  define h /display flow left width=12 'h';
  define i /display flow left width=10 'i';
  define j /display flow left width=11 'j';
  define k /display flow left width=12 'k' ;
  define l /display flow left width=12 'l';
  define n /display flow left width=14 'n';
  define m /display flow left width=158 'm' page;

  break after a /page;
      
  compute after _page_;
    line @1 165*'_';
  endcomp;
run;
   
proc printto;
run;
```

**Sample data**

```
data have;
  input a b c d e f g h i j k l n m;
datalines4;
...
... place your CSV sample data here
...
;;;;
```

Comment: Can you show some data?

Comment: Hi Richard, Yes, I can. I don't see an option to attach a .CSV file to provide it. Is it possible to attach such files here?   Thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: Edit your question and copy some of the CSV data into the area I prepared for you at the bottom of the question.  Only enough data that would make the proc replicate the problem.

Comment: If you can afford to print more characters on a line, try `options linesize=250;`, or any number that suites you.